# Python linear inheritance, middle class being overridden by child class on super() property calls

Tags: python, python-3.x, inheritance, properties

I have a class setup like so:

```
class A(object):
   __configuration = {}
   def __init__(self, configuration: dict = {}):
      A.__configuration = configuration
   
   @property
   def configuration(self):
      return A.__configuration

class B(A):
   def __init__(self, configuration: dict = {}):
      super().__init__(configuration=configuration)
   @property
   def configuration(self):
      return super().configuration.get('mammals')

class C(B):
   def __init__(self, configuration: dict = {}):
      super().__init__(configuration=configuration)
   @property
   def configuration(self):
      return super().configuration.get('human')
```

Now here is where I am running into something that I can't quite get around.

When I instantiate class C, it will call the super init to class B. Then, class B in turn calls a super init to class A.

The configuration will get set as a class variable in class A, and the property method when called will return that configuration/dict/class variable.

Class B I am attempting to have the configuration property get the super (class A's) configuration, then retrieve the 'mammals' value from it.

Class C then in turn I am attempting to (when called from class C) get the 'human' value from it's parent, which will call the class B's property, which I hoped would in turn call the class A's property... Thus resulting in a key / value lookup of:

1. get entire config
2. get the mammal value (which is another config/dict)
3. get the human value (type doesn't matter)

Problem:
When I instantiate class C, it propagates up to class A on instantiation as it should. Class A's configuration is set correctly. Then, in class B, when I reference that super().configuration, it ends up returning my CHILD (class C) 's configuration.

For example, if I put this line in my **init** in class B and let the instantiation carry out from instantiation class C:

print(self.configuration)
it would return to me the value for the human dictionary, NOT the mammals dictionary which is what I would like it to.

---

Here is an example of a configuration I would pass in when instantiating Class C:

```
config = {
   'mammals': {
      'human': {
         ...
      }
      ...
   }
   ...
}
exampleInstantiation = C(configuration=config)
```

I have been trying to look up linear inheritance, the ordering for the class method resolutions but I can't find anything that is giving me insight on why the MIDDLE class is being overridden by the child class.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you mean. What do you mean "the mammals dictionary"?

Comment: This code doesn't make sense. `A` has a class-level `__configuration` instead of instance-level, and all the default values have the mutable default bug.

Comment: What do you mean by the mutable default bug?

But @juanpa.arrivillaga, class B is referencing it's parent (class A)'s property of a configuration. I will update my comment to give an example of what the configuration passed in will look like.

Comment: [This bug.](https://docs.python.org/3/faq/programming.html#why-are-default-values-shared-between-objects)

Comment: `print(self.configuration)` will print `self.configuration`, not `self.this-class's-definition-of-configuration`. If `self` is a `C` instance, it'll use the `C` definition, even inside `B.__init__`. It respects override resolution, which you don't seem to have expected.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I updated my initial question. I accidentally switched class A and C up at one point describing my problem which might have completely confused whoever read the problem.

Comment: @user2357112supportsMonica I guess I'm looking for a way around that or reference to how I can dynamically work around that in the code without changing the current object type.

Comment: You should probably just change your design. A better design will give you a lot less problems - don't change the meaning of the `configuration` attribute in a subclass.

Comment: Yea I figure now that this design isn't proper. I'll probably set instance variables/configurations on the subclasses and maybe keep a base one just for a singleton.

Thank you for the help.